# Please explain the javascript: parameter in function call

Tags: javascript

Please explain the function call
what is the purpose of "/" in function call

```
initGraph(totalPaymentOutstanding / creditLimit, totalPayment / creditLimit, minPayment / totalPayment);



var initGraph = function(totalOutstanding, totalPayment, minPayment) {
//code here
....
..
}
```

Comment: `initGraph()` is a function and you haven't posted that function here... so how are we supposed to know?

Comment: It's a bit like `*`, `+` or `-`...

Comment: that function is used to draw graph. for that just we are passing some number as paramenter. In that just i need to know the "/" scope in function call.

Comment: It's a division operator, they are dividing e.g. `totalPaymentOutstanding` by `creditLimit` before sending it as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 totalPaymentOutstanding / creditLimit
```

totalPaymentOutstanding divided by creditLimit

/ is a Arithmetic operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators

Answer (score 2):

This is just a division. You divide `totalPaymentOutstanding` by `creditLimit` and you give the result as parameter to the function.